# Why using `eval` will not release memory later when using `unset` on anonymous function?

Tags: php, apache

The very simple PHP code below works perfectly, I mean, it does nothing and at the same time it does not use almost any system memory.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0); 
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');

for ($i=0;$i<100000000;$i++) {
        
    $bbb = function() {
    
        return true;

    };

    unset($bbb);
    
}

?>
```

While the code below is very similar BUT if you run it, after a few minutes you will crash your system because it will consume all your system RAM.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0); 
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');

for ($i=0;$i<100000000;$i++) {
    
    eval('
    
        $bbb = function() {
        
            return true;
    
        };
    
    ');

    unset($bbb);
    
}

?>
```

My actual `$bbb` function is much more complex and it is a result of my AI output, so I really need to use `eval` in this case. I am totally aware of security implications.

I just wanna know how to solve this problem. How can I make PHP/APACHE release memory (the GC probably is the curlprit) in the second case?

NOTE: I am using Windows 10 with PHP 7.4

EDIT

As per suggestion of @Nigel Ren (which looks very good) I tried this:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0); 
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');

for ($i=0;$i<100000000;$i++) {
    
    require("test.php");

    unset($bbb);
    
}

?>
```

And the "test.php" file has this:

```
<?php

$bbb = function() {

    return true;

};

?>
```

But this suggestion still consumes lots of memory, it's not getting cleared! Even if I use `gc_mem_caches();` GC is still not clearing memory. Maybe I understood something wrong from your suggestion @@Nigel Ren?

Comment: Could you manipulate the script file which runs the code, so rather than `eval` you paste the code into the script and run it then.

Comment: What do you mean by "AI output"?

Comment: @NigelRen I can paste the code in a script and run it if you think it's gonna help. How is this gonna fix my problem?

Comment: @Olivier AI generates the PHP code and later I need to evaluate it to check for precision.

Comment: But what is "AI"?

Comment: @Olivier Articial Inteligence

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Optimize a function? Is the function structure different each time, or just some parameters? If only parameters change, you don't need to reload the whole function, just the parameter values.

Comment: @Olivier I work for a company that uses machine learning to generate code after user says "I want a code that loops all prime numbers untill 100 and sums them all" and AI generates the code.

Comment: I'm surprised to see ML used with PHP. I thought ML guys were using Python or some other languages.

Comment: @Olivier PHP 7 is much faster than Python, most of the time almost twice as fast (in my several use cases). And when PHP is not fast enough I use Golang, and it always amazes me how fast it is. BUT working with arrays/slices on Golang sucks, it's terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of reseraching I discovered runkit7 is the way to go! It allows clearing RAM even from functions included/required/evaluated! You can use include/require/eval and it will wisely clean the memory footprint. It's a pretty awesome extension and I was amazed as soon as I tested it, my ram dropped 90% from the previous run I did without runkit7.

Answer (score 2):

See the last comment by Chris on [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69615).

For posterity's sake I'll copy it here:

> I became interested by the eval() behavior recently, and I can confirm that the memory usage gets higher by the time of the execution.
> However it is not really a bug, but the way eval() is fundamentally written:
>
> - it creates a temp file with the code inside (sometimes it is stored in memory)
> - it then includes that temp file using a normal include() function
>
> As you can see, the more eval() you do, the more include() it will trigger, resulting in a memory usage that cannot be freed...

So the reason your memory usages increases when using `eval` is that it's including temporary files. There's nu way to un-include files, so the more you use `eval`, the more memory you're going to end up using.

***Disclaimer:** the following is pure speculation, I have not verified if this will work*

As for a potential workaround to get around this issue, since you say you *need* to use `eval`, you could look into using [the `pcntl` extension](https://www.php.net/pcntl) to fork a process.

It's probably going to be slower, but if you can fork the `eval`-ing piece of your code off to a separate process which can then terminate gracefully once finished, the "include" performed in that child process *should* be cleared up. That might be one way to limit the memory usage in your application.

Comment: Thank you, that looks right but unfortunatelly your solution does not solve my problem because I run that code billions of time, and spawning a new process every time to eval, is gonna have a tremendous effect on my run time. I am already renting a machine on Linode for almost $ 2k a month, if I increase my loop time even by a small fraction, it's gonna break the bank! If you find another way to me declare a function and being able to unsed it, I would be glad! If you better answers come up, yours will definately be accepted!

Answer (score 1):

As a test, this code starts with a template for the source code in your first listing minus the definition but with a place holder to insert the code.  The script just reads this file, replaces the marker with the AI script and writes a new file (abc1.php), then uses `require` to run the script.  This removes any need for `eval` and the overheads associated with it...

So abc.php is

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');

for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    
    //#
    
    unset($bbb);
    
}
```

The bootstrap script is, where `$aiSrc` is the code you generate (note this also runs the function)...

```
$src = file_get_contents("abc.php");
$aiSrc = '$bbb = function() {
    
        echo "Hello";

    };

$bbb();';

$newSrc = str_replace("//#", $aiSrc, $src);
file_put_contents("abc1.php", $newSrc);

require"abc1.php";
```

After this the script abc1.php contains...

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');

for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    
    $bbb = function() {
    
        echo "Hello";

    };

$bbb();
    
    unset($bbb);
    
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty great idea! I think it may even run faster than my eval since eval is so slow! I will give it a try right now!

Comment: could you please read my EDIT? I couldnt reply you here in the comments with a code, so I pasted it at the bottom of my question ok? Did I missed something?

Comment: @Samul This code still uses a lot of `require`. From the other answer: "the more include() it will trigger, resulting in a memory usage that cannot be freed".

Comment: @Olivier as per your last comment, as and per the first answer I got in this question, anything included with `include`, `require`... will never be cleared by PHP even after unsetting all variables/functions inside of it?

Comment: @Samul It's surprising indeed but it seems that `include` creates a leak.

Comment: The idea is that the `require` is removed from the loop and the actual code is 'pasted' into the loop of the code.

Comment: @Olivier indeed, I tried `include` and `require` and I could never imagine that! I thought PHP would the included file code before compiling, exactly as if I had copied/pasted the included file in the right place. But no, PHP is again doing something weird and preventing memory optimization.

Comment: @NigelRen I did what you said but I need to require billions of times the file because my `$bbb` function changes every single time I set it. I will just run it once.